# Have TypeScript class inherit from JS object without a complete definition

Tags: inheritance, typescript

I have a large JS library that is a dependency. It does not have a TypeScript definition file and making one would be very cumbersome. As a work around, we have used the following definition file, which essentially just disables typechecking for that library:

```
declare var library: any;
```

I need to extend one object from this library. Currently this is done via vanilla JS inheritance:

```
function Bar(argument: any) {
    library.Foo.call(this, argument);

    // Other properties...
};
Bar.prototype = Object.create(library.Foo.prototype);
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;
```

I'd like to convert this to use TypeScript's `class` syntax for consistency with the rest of my TS code and because I find that syntax cleaner and more readable. I expected it to be like this:

```
class Bar extends library.Foo {
    constructor(argument: any) {
        super(argument);
    }

    // Other properties...
}
```

But this fails with the error "cannot find namespace 'library'", despite the fact that I'm able to use stuff like `library.Whatever` elsewhere with no issues (thanks to the definition file that declares `library` as having unknown properties).

Is there anything I can do here? Preferably without having to create a definition file for this large library.

Comment: I am facing exact same issue. Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

A class can only extend from another class. Thats why if you want to stick with you style (writing a class definition instead of JS inheritance), you will need to create a class that represents Foo and merge it with the existing class. e.g.

```
declare var library: any|ILibrary;

function mix(target: any, ingredients: any[]) {
    ingredients.forEach(e => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e.prototype).forEach(f => {
            target.prototype[f] = e.prototype[f];
        });
    });
}

interface ILibrary {
    Foo: Bar|any;
}

class Bar {

}
mix(library.Foo, [Bar]);
```

With this setup we can add things to the Bar class and it will get merged into `library.Foo`. If we were to add a function `help` we could then call it via `library.Foo.help()`. Problem is we can't use any local members because `Bar` without defining it. e.g.

```
class Bar {
    version: number; // something from the JS library
    getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }
}
```